# Google Analytics: How to find the URLs accesed through organic traffic?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search, analytics

I'm trying to analyze the traffic through the organic searches in order to determine which URLs are the most "popular" through search engines. And would like to find such URLs.

In my Google Analytics account, I've done the following selection:

Behavior > Site Content > All Pages > [I selected a specific period of time] > Add Segment > Organic Traffic, and then I sorted the URLs by "Entrances". I understand that visitors entered my website through those URLs.

Is this selection correct?

Comment: That's one way of doing it.  Have you also looked at Acquisition>Overview >Click on Organic Traffic in the results>and as Secondary Dimension adding Landing Page?  Keep in mind that "All Pages" includes pages your users navigated to using your internal links, whereas Landing Pages is one your users landed on from external sources.

Answer (score 1):

In Google Analytics you have multiple ways to see your *organic landing pages* the most easy/needed ones are:

1. Go to: Acquisition > Channels > "Organic" + Second Dimension "Landing Pages"
2. Use the "Organic" segment and go to: Behaviour > Site Content > Landing Pages
3. Go to Behaviour > Site Content > Landing Pages + Second Dimension "Source" + Filter for Organic

Besides that you can have a look at [the queries report within Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1308626?hl=en#queries), which will also show impressions, ctr and average rankings.